# How to share the image to gallery with the url in android facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),mBitmap, new Request.Callback() {                        
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            savedBitmap = saveBitmapToStorage();
            if (response.getError() == null && savedBitmap != null) {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info),ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.publishing));
                new APIHandler(ctx,tracker,"uploadImg").execute(ctx,shareTxt,savedBitmap,catId);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                Toast.makeText(ctx, response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Utility.showDialog(ctx,"error",tracker,false);
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    shareTxt = shareContent.getText().toString() == "" ? getResources().getString(R.string.default_msg) : shareContent.getText().toString();
    params.putString("message", shareTxt);
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
```

In my facebook share code, I would like to share image with the url, however, it does not work , only the image and the message is shown in facebook , how to fix it ? thanks

There is a warning but i am not sure whether it is relevant

```
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43654640 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:662)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:344)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:228)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:586)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at com.project.hkseven.Activity.SharePicForm$3.onCompleted(SharePicForm.java:263)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1669)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4882)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 00:54:20.353: W/System.err(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 00:54:20.363: W/System.err(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-18 00:54:20.363: W/System.err(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-18 00:54:20.363: W/System.err(1062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 00:54:20.704: W/dalvikvm(1062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f1f438)
```

Comment: can you check whether there was any error in the logcat or not??

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK does not allow you to share an image and a url at the same time. If it is an image, the url will be excluded. If you do a normal post with a url, an image will be selected from the website and you can't put custom images on it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the url to the parms("message") . The facebook will handle automatically